# what effects will the transformation f(x) = 1/(1+e^(-x)) have on the gray levels of an image?

Tags: image, image-processing

so the range of pixels is between 0 and 255,

if we put 0 we will have 1/2 and then from 3 all the way to 255 will will have 1

does that mean that any greyscale picture will tun to black if that transformation was applied to it ?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: It's a horrible transformation: e^(-x) is computationally expensive. Can you think of a faster approximation?

Comment: I think that transformation would be better suited for images that have been scaled to [0..1] (i.e. floating-point pixel values).

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Sigmoidal Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and it is very good contrast function.
Yet you should scale the numbers into the [0, 1] range (Floating Point) and then apply it.

You can parameterize the coefficient before the exponent argument.